# Cannot sign in because game asks for my date of birth and I cannot remember which date I had written

Tags: pokemon-go

Trying to make AR work on my mobile,, I cleared data and cache of my Pokémon Go app on my mobile. After that, when I tried to sign in as a returning player, I was asked for my trainer's club code and password which I don't think I ever had. I know how to sign in with my email and password but how to get to the screen where email and password are required for signing in?

About AR, are there any specific settings for Samsung Note 9? 
Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the initial login question - if it's the date of birth that you're asked for before selecting a login method (Google, Apple ID, Trainer Club etc) then you can add in anything at all.  It doesn't matter if it's the DOB you originally entered.